# Identity Server: Refresh Token for the currently Authenticated User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

Authentication configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
        };
        
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Home";
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Account/SignOutCallback";

        options.Authority = Authority;
        options.ClientId = ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        
        //Scopes is "Api.Scope", "offline_access"
        foreach (var scope in Scopes)
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }

        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

this configuration redirect to the identity server login when using the `Autorize` attribute in a controller

the access token:

```
var accessToken = await _contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

the client Access Token Lifetime is configured to 120 for test purposes so the token expires in 2 minutes.

the client application is an MVC Web application and i use the External Login method to authenticate the user via AD. because in order to call the API i need all user informations
(roles and claims).
following this method from the documentation :
https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/2_interactive/

now the question is how to refresh the access token when it exprires.

Answer (score 0):

This works for identity server 4 code flow.
In IdentityServer config, add `AllowOfflineAccess=true,` and `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess` to allowed scopes.
[image]
In Client side oidc authentication,after adding `options.Scope.Add("offline_access");`
Then your could see the refresh token by

```
<dl>
    @foreach (var prop in (await Context.AuthenticateAsync()).Properties.Items)
    {
        <dt>@prop.Key</dt>
        <dd>@prop.Value</dd>
    }
</dl>
```

[image]